Will Pachira Aquatica have branches?
About one year ago I bought two Pachira Aquatica together in a pot (They are not "braided"). The height is about 1.7m. I'm keeping them indoors, due to a lack of choices.
Both plants seem to grow just taller, with new leaves around the top. Since this is a "tree" I am wondering if it will also have branches, emerging to the sides and filling some the horizontal space, and if there is a way to promote their creation. The trunk doesn't show any signs like buds, no changes after lignification.




Hard to help you if you won't supply a pic. Youtube on money tree care could be a good start.

I added the requested photos. I assume that it means that money trees can build branches and you can tell about the chances from looking at the plant?
